# Keyboard script for pressing a key

Tags: linux, keyboard

I am looking for a simple linux program that will allow my keyboard to press a key for few seconds and then another one for few other seconds.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is off-topic, but what you're looking for is `xdotool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), which lets you simulate keyboard input.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool  

#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 0 9`;
do
  xdotool key $i
done
```

**UPDATE**

To simulate a pressing a key for six seconds in Bash, then simulate pressing a different one  for a further six seconds will be painful.

Therefore, I would use Ruby (you might have to install this from the repositories).

```
ruby -e 't = Time.new.to_i; key = "a"; while true do `xdotool key #{key}`; key = "b" if Time.new.to_i > t + 6; break if Time.new.to_i > t + 12; end'
```

If you run this from the command line it will simulate pressing key "a" for six seconds, after which it'll simulate a pressing key "b" for a further six.

Comment: Thank you, this is exatly what i was looking for.
How to press a key for few second, i don't mean press it few times but let it be pressed for 6 seconds and then another key for 6 other seconds ?

Comment: I have somme lag issues but it works, the button is not fluent but it is ok.